# Le (la) « (touche) Carré » : applications, différences, cohérence ?

Tags: vocabulaire, accord, informatique, majuscules, téléphone

En ce qui a trait à la « touche de clavier d'un appareil téléphonique, sur laquelle apparaît un symbole constitué de deux paires de lignes parallèles entrecroisées en forme de croix [...] » le GDT (OQLF) privilégie le terme « [touche Carré](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872307) » ou « Carré » alors que dans la langue courante on a « touche Dièse » (on remarquera les [majuscules](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1280)), et non « touche Croisillon » ou « Croisillon », le *carré* et le [*croisillon*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26544259) (voir aussi l'ébauche sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croisillon_(signe))) référant au même symbole par ailleurs, auquel on réfère par *dièse* dans la langue courante...

D'autre part avec les versions d'Android postérieures à 4.x et [antérieures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_8.1_Oreo_(API_27)) à 9.x par exemple, on avait dans la barre de navigation au bas de l'interface trois icônes, dont celui de droite était soit un rectangle soit un carré selon les itérations.

---

- Dans un reproduction virtuelle d'un clavier, parle-t-on d'une touche
  (*Carré*) ou d'un symbole (*carré*) ; est-ce qu'on touche/fait *une
  touche* (*touchez/faites la touche Carré*) ou on touche/fait *le
  symbole* (*touchez/faites le carré/Carré*) ?
- Peut-on préciser la nature et la fonction de la majuscule employée :
  s'agit-il d'une mise en valeur, comment et pourquoi ; l'invariabilité
  suffisait-elle (carré, touche *carrée*); pourquoi pas les guillemets
  ou les italiques ?
- Sur Android selon les paramètres mentionnés, comme désigne-t-on
  l'élément de droite et avec quel verbe explique-t-on d'y avoir
  recours ?

Comment: Déçu de voir que Jardin de Frosted Flakes a supprimé son compte :(

Answer (score 1):

J'avoue que je ne comprends pas vraiment la décision de l'OQLF d'appeler ça "touche Carré", ni pour la majuscule ni pour ce qui est de toute évidence soit un dièse soit un croisillon.

Surtout que dans la plupart des services téléphoniques, on entend des "*pour [action], appuyez sur dièse*".

Pour ce qui est des "triangle/rond/carré" sur les android récents (https://img.phonandroid.com/2017/10/android-oreo-navigation-1024x576.jpg), dans les menu android ils s'appellent "boutons".

Ce sera donc le "*bouton carré*" (si on veut le désigner par sa forme, dans le menu ils sont appelés respectivement "*bouton retour*", "*bouton accueil*" et "*bouton récents*").

Answer (score 1):

- Dans un reproduction virtuelle d'un clavier, parle-t-on d'une touche
  (Carré) ou d'un symbole (carré) ; est-ce qu'on touche/fait une touche
  (touchez/faites la touche Carré) ou on touche/fait le symbole
  (touchez/faites le carré/Carré) ?

Premièrement d'après l'[OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872307) Il ne faut parler de touche carré lorsqu'il s'agit d'un appareil physique et d'une touche physique, cette appellation ne s'applique donc pas aux touches virtuelles d'un clavier virtuel. (Voir image)

[image]

- Peut-on préciser la nature et la fonction de la majuscule employée :
  s'agit-il d'une mise en valeur, comment et pourquoi ; l'invariabilité
  suffisait-elle (carré, touche carrée); pourquoi pas les guillemets ou
  les italiques ?

La majuscule permet ici d'utiliser *Carré* sous la forme de nom propre, plutôt que de nom commun, car il s'agit bien de la *touche dièse* en métropole qui n'as dont pas une forme carré au sens premier du terme.

- Sur Android selon les paramètres mentionnés, comme désigne-t-on
  l'élément de droite et avec quel verbe explique-t-on d'y avoir
  recours ?

Sur Android, ceci est appelé une barre de navigation et le bouton de droite fait souvent référence aux *"applications récentes"* à noter que la disposition ainsi que l'effet des boutons dépend entièrement de la [surcouche Android](https://www.papergeek.fr/surcouche-android-quel-smartphone-a-la-meilleure-interface-78548) et donc de la marque du smartphone.

[image]